Where is the cliff from the cut scene?
I was playing Avatar: Frontiers of Pandora last night, I was flying around the area next to where Drill Base Omega was located. I was trying to find where the cliff is that they are on during the cut scene at the end of the quest, where they all meet up and you see the charge detonate in the distance at Drill Base Omega. Where is the cliff located? I'm starting to think that the cliff might only exist in the cut scene, though it'll be the only location in a cut scene which I don't think exists in game.

Found it in the end. If you look out for two Ikran Gear Baskets in the floating mountains to the south of the Drill Base Omega site, it's to the south of the eastern one. It's also to the west of the Story Teller's Stone (and is at around the same height as the Story Teller's Stone).
I didn't find it before as I was looking further west of where it actually was.
This is about where it's located on the map:

When you reach the site, you'll be able see Anqa's helicopter still there (think it's a Samson):

